# Headless unit testing for WebView2

Tags: .net, wpf, webview2, .net-4.6.1

I'm writing unit tests for a class that wraps the WebView2 browser control (WPF version if it matters).

Is there a way to run WebView2 in the equivalent of a headless mode so I don't have to actually load a window in order to test it? I've tried passing `--headless` in as an additional browser argument but `EnsureCoreWebView2Async` still spins forever so I assume it's one of the ignored arguments.

Comment: If you are really unit testing a class that wraps the `WebView2`, you should mock the control. Otherwise it's not really a unit test of your class.

Comment: @mm8 We mock the wrapper. The uncovered code are hardcoded WebView2 configurations and javascript calls that are essentially just simple getters/setters. Mocking the control is an option but the value would be minimal. My hope is that there is a simple way to get a little more coverage for stuff that I would otherwise not worry too much about. Since WebView2 is newer and based on tech that supported headless I figured that might be possible.

Comment: Not sure if its possible through some command line args but it is not currently supported through the WebView2 API surface. You can open a feature request: https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/new/choose

Comment: Just as a reference, it seems that using `HWND_MESSAGE` as described in [#202](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/202) allows to use WebView2 headless e.g. in a .NET Console application.